# Reviewing a suggested edit from a review queue jumps to the suggested edit queue

Tags: feature-request, review, suggested-edits

I was in the first posts review queue and chanced on a post with a suggested edit. (Note: I have enough reputation to review suggested edits.) I clicked on “edit (1)” and was taken into the suggested edits queue. When I approved the suggested edit, I was taken to the next suggested edit, and so on until there were no more suggestions (“There are no items for you to review.”, still in the suggested edits queue).

In this situation, I think it would make more sense if I was brought back to that post I was working on in the first posts queue, as soon as I acted on its suggested edit. Alternatively, the suggested edit should be shown in the same kind of pop-up as on a question thread page. The same goes for other queues (late answers, low quality, etc.).

Comment: Or a back button placed where the approve/reject buttons are (you're hovering around).

Comment: Related: [Adding a post notice makes me exit the review queue](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148386/adding-a-post-notice-makes-me-exit-the-review-queue)

Comment: It does this from the moderator flag queue too. I have a [feature request pending](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/153166/allow-moderators-to-handle-suggested-edits-without-leaving-the-dashboard) for that.

Comment: Related: [Reviewing a suggested edit should count as an action in the First Posts/Late Answers review queues](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/327140/571958). Approaching the issue from the angle that the edit review doesn't count as an action on that first/late post