# Adding a post notice makes me exit the review queue

Tags: bug, status-completed, review, post-notices

I was just reviewing a few post in the "first posts" review queue and noticed that when I added a post notice inside the review queue, I'm redirected to the normal version of the post outside the review queue. I can get back to the review queue using the back button of my browser, but it would be nice if it worked like all other actions inside the queue.

And this is not a rare case on Skeptics, many new answers don't fulfill our citation requirements and need a "citation needed" notice. The review queue is a nice tool for that.

Comment: Related: [Reviewing a suggested edit from a review queue jumps to the suggested edit queue](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148004/reviewing-a-suggested-edit-from-a-review-queue-jumps-to-the-suggested-edit-queue) and probably several other little annoyances related to the flow through review queues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've updated most mod popup actions to keep you on the queue if that's where you came from.

This should be out there in the next build.

Comment: Does this apply just in the review queue, or does it work in the mod queue as well?

Comment: @casperOne - `/review/*` only ATM.

Answer (score 2):

I [recently reported](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4039/25936) this on Meta Programmers for all mod actions taken through review:

> when doing anything from the mod menu (the one that works), you're redirected to the post's page instead of the post's review page. Not sure if this is a bug or a feature request, but it would be nice if we were redirected back where we came from, to continue reviewing.

[Emmett's answer](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4054/25936) seems to indicate that there are plans for a better workflow, but it's not really a high priority:

> We're aware that the mod-menu-from-review flow is sub-optimal, and it's on our TODO. We just haven't prioritized it to the top yet, since it affects a small minority of users (albeit important ones).

This sounds like a [status-deferred](/questions/tagged/status-deferred) to me.

Comment: So I'll have to finally write my feature request to make post notices a community feature to speed this up ;-)

Comment: @MadScientist No, you don't need to write it, a bounty would do: [Allow 10k, 15k, or 20k users to add post notices](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141931/allow-10k-15k-or-20k-users-to-add-post-notices)