# Allow moderators to handle suggested edits without leaving the dashboard

Tags: feature-request, suggested-edits, moderator-tools

As moderators work through our queue of flagged questions and answers, we sometimes happen upon posts that have pending suggested edits.

We're able to view and handle the suggested edit prior to taking action, however, once handling a suggested edit we find ourselves in the ... you guessed it ... suggested edit queue. We then have to go back to the moderation queue, find the post we were working on and then service the flag.

Would it be possible for us to 'bypass' the suggested edit queue if we're approving, improving or declining a suggested edit from the moderator dashboard? The current workaround is to open the suggested edit dialog in a new tab. Ideally, that shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: Can you speak to the people that be about this and the same bug in the First Posts queue? I've revived both feature requests http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/259720/dont-move-me-to-the-suggested-edits-queue-from-the-first-posts